# Placement of conjunctival adverbs, after or before “is, are...”!

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, grammaticality-in-context

Placement of conjunctival adverbs.

> - 1 John is a student. He, however, **is** a worker.
> - 2 John is a student. He **is**, however, a worker.

Where the conjunctival adverbs should be placed when interrupt a sentence : after or before Verb-be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is possible, but the emphasis is different. If you want to emphasize **he**, you say

> She works hard. **He**, however, is lazy.

If you want to place the emphasis on what he is, you can say

> He has the right qualifications. He is, however, **lazy**.